# En python ¿Como agregar una columna a un data frame, donde los valores dependan de un rango?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy comenzando en programación con Python y tengo la siguiente situación:

Tengo un `DataFrame` donde una de las columnas son las edades, pero quiero agregar otra columna que indique el rango al que pertenece. Por ejemplo "18-25","26-35","36-45","46-55","56-65","66-75","76-85","85+". Traté de hacer el sigueinte codigo pero no funcionó.

[image: Ejemplo de código]

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Podés usar el objeto range en caso de trabajar con rangos finitos de números enteros. Ej: range(18, 26).

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: ¿Quieres que esos rangos se decidan automáticamente? ¿O quieres usar esos rangos que indicas tú específicamente? Si sabes de antemano qué rangos usar, te recomiendo usar el método [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). Si quieres que se generen automáticamente, usa  [`pandas.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html#pandas.qcut).

Comment: Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La razón por la que no te funciona lo que estás intentando hacer es porque esa no es la sintaxis para declarar condiciones. En `Python`, como en muchos otros lenguajes, es importante declarar 2 valores para la condición. Es decir

```
ValorAComparar <= ValorLimite
```

Eso lo haces bien en tu primera comparación, pero cuando intentas adjuntar una segunda condición solo pusiste `& >= ValorLimite`. `Python` no puede decifrar que valor deseas comparar con el límite que estás definiendo por lo que la comparación para el primer rango sería:

```
df['Edad'] <= 26 & df['Edad'] >= 18
```

En `Python` puedes comparar un valor con un límite inferior y uno superior de una forma un poco más compacta:

```
ValorInferior <= ValorAComparar <= ValorSuperior
```

Por lo que la comparación del primer rango podría quedar así:

```
18 <= df['Edad'] <= 26
```

**Nota:** Si no deseas incluir los límites simplemente cambias `<=` por `<`.

Otro método que creo es un poco más claro es utilizar [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) en conjunto con [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

Como no agregaste tus datos, cree un ejemplo genérico que tendrás que adaptar a tu código:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(18, 80+1)), columns=['Edad'])

# Definimos donde se van a "cortar" los rangos, se deben incluir el mínimo y el máximo
rangos = [18, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85]

# Definimos las etiquetas, la longitud de la lista es de rangos - 1
etiquetas = ['De 18 a 25',
             'De 26 a 35',
             'De 36 a 45',
             'De 46 a 55',
             'De 56 a 65',
             'De 66 a 75',
             'De 76 a 85']

# Creamos una nueva columna con el nombre de las etiquetas
df['Rango'] = pd.cut(df['Edad'], rangos, labels = etiquetas, include_lowest = True)

# Agrupamos por rango y con cumcount creamos un nuevo "indice"
df['Index'] = df.groupby(['Rango'])['Edad'].cumcount()

# Hacemos pivot sobre la columna "Rango" con "Index" como índice
# Rellenamos los valores vacíos con "N/A"
resultado = df.pivot(columns = 'Rango', index = 'Index').fillna('N/A')
print(resultado)
```

Este ejemplo utiliza un `dataframe` con una sola columna que contiene la edad, de esta forma:

```
    Edad
0     18
1     19
2     20
3     21
4     22
..   ...
58    76
59    77
60    78
61    79
62    80

[63 rows x 1 columns]
```

Y al finalizar imprime lo siguiente:

```
            Edad                                                                  
Rango De 18 a 25 De 26 a 35 De 36 a 45 De 46 a 55 De 56 a 65 De 66 a 75 De 76 a 85
Index                                                                             
0           18.0       26.0       36.0       46.0       56.0       66.0       76.0
1           19.0       27.0       37.0       47.0       57.0       67.0       77.0
2           20.0       28.0       38.0       48.0       58.0       68.0       78.0
3           21.0       29.0       39.0       49.0       59.0       69.0       79.0
4           22.0       30.0       40.0       50.0       60.0       70.0       80.0
5           23.0       31.0       41.0       51.0       61.0       71.0        N/A
6           24.0       32.0       42.0       52.0       62.0       72.0        N/A
7           25.0       33.0       43.0       53.0       63.0       73.0        N/A
8            N/A       34.0       44.0       54.0       64.0       74.0        N/A
9            N/A       35.0       45.0       55.0       65.0       75.0        N/A
```